# C OpenSSL: loading an RSA public key via d2i_PublicKey() fails

Tags: c, openssl

Ok, I have an RSA public key, and I want to load it into openssl so I can do something with it.

For clarity, the bytes themselves appear to be in "DER" format, and are generally fine:

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ openssl rsa -pubin -in myfile.dat  -inform der -noout -text
RSA Public-Key: (1024 bit)
Modulus:
    00:df:ec:1a:d6:2c:10:66:2c:17:35:3a:14:b0:7c:
    59:11:7f:9d:d3:d8:2b:7a:e3:e0:15:cd:19:1e:46:
    e8:7b:87:74:a2:18:46:31:a9:03:14:79:82:8e:e9:
    45:a2:49:12:a9:23:68:73:89:cf:69:a1:b1:61:46:
    bd:c1:be:bf:d6:01:1b:d8:81:d4:dc:90:fb:fe:4f:
    52:73:66:cb:95:70:d7:c5:8e:ba:1c:7a:33:75:a1:
    62:34:46:bb:60:b7:80:68:fa:13:a7:7a:8a:37:4b:
    9e:c6:f4:5d:5f:3a:99:f9:9e:c4:3a:e9:63:a2:bb:
    88:19:28:e0:e7:14:c0:42:89
Exponent: 17 (0x11)
```

Having verified this, I try to do this in code:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include <cstdio>

/************************************************************************/

static const uint8_t publicKey[160]=
{
    0x30, 0x81, 0x9D, 0x30, 0x0D, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
    0x05, 0x00, 0x03, 0x81, 0x8B, 0x00, 0x30, 0x81, 0x87, 0x02, 0x81, 0x81, 0x00, 0xDF, 0xEC, 0x1A,
    0xD6, 0x2C, 0x10, 0x66, 0x2C, 0x17, 0x35, 0x3A, 0x14, 0xB0, 0x7C, 0x59, 0x11, 0x7F, 0x9D, 0xD3,
    0xD8, 0x2B, 0x7A, 0xE3, 0xE0, 0x15, 0xCD, 0x19, 0x1E, 0x46, 0xE8, 0x7B, 0x87, 0x74, 0xA2, 0x18,
    0x46, 0x31, 0xA9, 0x03, 0x14, 0x79, 0x82, 0x8E, 0xE9, 0x45, 0xA2, 0x49, 0x12, 0xA9, 0x23, 0x68,
    0x73, 0x89, 0xCF, 0x69, 0xA1, 0xB1, 0x61, 0x46, 0xBD, 0xC1, 0xBE, 0xBF, 0xD6, 0x01, 0x1B, 0xD8,
    0x81, 0xD4, 0xDC, 0x90, 0xFB, 0xFE, 0x4F, 0x52, 0x73, 0x66, 0xCB, 0x95, 0x70, 0xD7, 0xC5, 0x8E,
    0xBA, 0x1C, 0x7A, 0x33, 0x75, 0xA1, 0x62, 0x34, 0x46, 0xBB, 0x60, 0xB7, 0x80, 0x68, 0xFA, 0x13,
    0xA7, 0x7A, 0x8A, 0x37, 0x4B, 0x9E, 0xC6, 0xF4, 0x5D, 0x5F, 0x3A, 0x99, 0xF9, 0x9E, 0xC4, 0x3A,
    0xE9, 0x63, 0xA2, 0xBB, 0x88, 0x19, 0x28, 0xE0, 0xE7, 0x14, 0xC0, 0x42, 0x89, 0x02, 0x01, 0x11,
};

/************************************************************************/

int main()
{
    const uint8_t* bytes=publicKey;
    EVP_PKEY* pkey=d2i_PublicKey(EVP_PKEY_RSA, nullptr, &bytes, 160);
    if (pkey==nullptr)
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

... but, that doesn't work:

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp -lcrypto
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ ./a.out
1000EFB6:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1188:
1000EFB6:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:752:
1000EFB6:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:685:Field=n, Type=RSAPublicKey
1000EFB6:error:0688000D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PublicKey:ASN1 lib:../crypto/asn1/d2i_pu.c:60:
```

Yes, it's the same bytes as before:

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ hexdump -C myfile.dat | head -1
00000000  30 81 9d 30 0d 06 09 2a  86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 01  |0..0...*.H......|
```

And, I'm completely lost. Manpages suggest that the d2i functions are indeed taking "DER" data, and the command line tool appears to accept it as such... I checked the header file and found an `EVP_PKEY_RSA2` but that doesn't seem to help. The function name clearly says "PublicKey" so I'm assuming the `-pubin` from the command line tool is covered, I'm clearing stating that it's an RSA key... and there really aren't a whole lot of parameters to play with.

Comment: Try d2i_PUBKEY instead. d2i_PublicKey and d2i_PUBKEY are confusingly similar. The former will read an RSA key in PKCS1 format. The latter will read any public key (not just RSA) in SubjectPublicKeyInfo format.

Comment: You key is indeed in PKCS1 format, you can check that with this cool ASN.1 JavaScript decoder: 
https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQDf7BrWLBBmLBc1OhSwfFkRf53T2Ct64-AVzRkeRuh7h3SiGEYxqQMUeYKO6UWiSRKpI2hzic9pobFhRr3Bvr_WARvYgdTckPv-T1JzZsuVcNfFjrocejN1oWI0Rrtgt4Bo-hOneoo3S57G9F1fOpn5nsQ66WOiu4gZKODnFMBCiQIBEQ

So after reading it with `d2i_PUBKEY`, as recommended by Matt, you can use `EVP_PKEY_print_public` to get the same output that your OpenSSL command line shows.

Comment: @MattCaswell yeah, that function seems to do the trick, thanks :-)

Sorry for late response, I had more important things to deal with...